# How to set background color to <p> tag in html ; so that background color doesn't exceed the text?

Tags: css, html

I'm trying following:

```
    p { margin: 0 0 1.5em; background-color: #eff0f1;}
```

to set background for `<p>` elements; but the background is stretched so long; I want this background to be present as much as there is text.[image]

Comment: `display:inline` - and since that will likely mess up the document flow, you might want to rather put a span element into the paragraph, and apply the background color to that. (`inline-block`, as some answers are suggesting, will of course not work once the text breaks into multiple lines.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
p {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: what if I want little more to start and end?

Comment: padding: 0 1rem; //?

Comment: 1rem equals the font size of the html element

Comment: @kushal More explicitly, one `rem` is the size of one `em` of the _root_ node, regardless of percentages or other ems in between - see [Understanding and Using rem Units in CSS](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-and-using-rem-units-in-css/)

Answer (score 2):

Just set `display: inline-block;` to that paragraph or `<p>`

With your code it would be:

```
p { margin: 0 0 1.5em; background-color: #eff0f1; display: inline-block;}
```

You can see a working example here: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hts1baq0/)

Answer (score 1):

`float: left` would work. But it can cause problems. Maybe you can provide more infomation?
here's sample fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/t80twe4y/